# I am trying to scrape a wikipedia page in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, wikipedia, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue. My target is to store all 50 rows in the table to csv file.

But I am not able to do so. Please find the code attached.

```
// Importing necessary modules

const request = require("request-promise")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const fs      = require("fs")
const json2csv = require("json2csv").Parser

// page which i want to scrape
const wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue";

(async () => {

    // this will store the data
    let data = [];

    // making request
    const response = await request({
        uri: wiki,
        headers: { 
                        accept:
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        },
        gzip: true,
    });

    let $ = cheerio.load(response);


      // Extracting rank and name of the company, it will be only for 1st row
      // I will run a loop 50 times to get 50 rows. But below two lines are not working

     // on testing this line on chrome console, it is giving correct output , but it is not working   
     // here, same thing for name
        let rank = $('table[class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"] tbody tr:nth-child(1) th').text();

        let name = $('table[class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"] tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').text();

     // saving data
        data.push({
            rank,
            name,
        });

    // exporting to csv
    const j2cp = new json2csv()
    const csv = j2cp.parse(data);

    fs.writeFileSync("./imdb1.csv", csv, "utf-8");
}
)();
```

Please let me know where is the mistake. I am following this tutorial in case you want to know something about code. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqGq9MTSt7g
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try your code, and it seems that the jquery selector used is okay, but somehow cheerio returns null. Here is my modified code, updated to get other columns as well:

```
    var req = require("request-promise"),
        cheerio = require("cheerio"),
        fs = require("fs"),
        json2csv = require("json2csv").Parser;

    // page which i want to scrape
    const wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue";

    (async () => {
        const response = await req({
            uri: wiki,
            headers: {
                accept:
                    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            },
            gzip: true,
        }).then(function (html) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let data = [];
            let data2 = [];
            let name, rank, cols, col;
            let rows = $('table.wikitable tbody tr').each((idx, elem) => {
                rank =$(elem).find('th').text().replace(/[\n\r]+/g,'');
                //name = $(elem).find('td a').html();
                data2 = [];
                cols = $(elem).find('td').each((colidx, colelem) => {
                    col = $(colelem).text().replace(/[\n\r]+/g,'');
                    data2.push(col,);    
                });

                data.push({
                    rank,
                    ...data2,
                });
            });

            // exporting to csv
            const j2cp = new json2csv()
            const csv = j2cp.parse(data);

            fs.writeFileSync("./imdb1.csv", csv, "utf-8");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }
    )();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I want to ask one thing. Why my jquery is giving null. It is working in browser and second thing, how to extract other td using your method ? Can you share any link which will help me in extracting other column values.

Comment: sorry, wrong comment above. I already updated it. pls see above

Comment: Thanks you very much. Any reason why cheerio is giving null ?